# .json.rabl not showing in view for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view, rabl

Trying to get User model to print to JSON, tried making a file with a json.rabl extension as follows:

file.json.rabl

```
object @users

attributes :id, :name
```

When I try to view this, I get the following error message:

```
Missing template users/autocomplete, application/autocomplete with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :rabl, :rb]}.
```

However, if I rename the file to file.rabl, it renders the JSON, but in an HTML page instead. How do I get it to print a pure JSON file?

Here is my controller code for the file view:

```
def file
@users = User.all
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.json
end
```

Comment: Have you installed rabl gem?

Comment: Yup, restarted the server as well. The .rabl extension on its own works fine but that renders it as an HTML page, not a JSON file.

Comment: Try adding respond_to :html, :json to the top of your controller.

Comment: See this link https://github.com/nesquena/rabl Hope it helps.

Comment: And this one too http://www.rodrigoalvesvieira.com/developing-json-api-rails-rabl/

Comment: Had a look at the first link when I downloaded Rabl, and adding respond_to :html, :json at the top of my controller isn't working. The rails app recognises .rabl extensions, it's the .json.rabl extension that seems to be the issue. I was thinking it might be an issue with routes but you don't specify formats in routes, so I'm still stumped.

Comment: I have one doubt.If the template name is file.json.rabl,then why the error is referring to users/autocomplete, application/autocomplete?Are you rendering that file in those actions?

Comment: Just figured it out, have to add .json to the URL in the browser! Rookie error :P

Comment: Glad you found it.Anyways I learned a new topic.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just had to add `.json` to the `URL`.

Comment: Accept your own answer,so that this Question will be closed.